# Convert hive queries to pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hope everything doing well!!

I want to convert below hive queries to pyspark in order to improve the performance.

`````
        CREATE TABLE ts_tot AS
SELECT a.mkt_offr_src_cd AS mkt_offr_src_cd,
a.offer_cd10 AS offer_cd10,
a.rp_offr_nm AS rp_offr_nm,
b.bus_unit AS bus_unit,
b.source_code AS compass_source_code,
b.compass_offer_type AS compass_offer_type
FROM ts_tot_incv a
LEFT OUTER JOIN ts_tot_incv_5 b
ON Trim(a.mkt_offr_src_cd) = Trim(b.source_code)
where a.mkt_offr_src_cd='A' and b.bus_unit='X';````
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

ts_tot_incv = spark.table("ts_tot_incv").where(F.col("mkt_offr_src_cd") == "A").select("mkt_offr_src_cd","offer_cd10","rp_offr_nm") # Fetching Data from ts_tot_incv & applying where condition. you can remove if don't want.

ts_tot_incv_5 = spark.table("ts_tot_incv_5").where(F.col("bus_unit") == "X").select("bus_unit","source_code".alias("compass_source_code"),"compass_offer_type") # Fetching data from ts_tot_incv_5 table & also applying where condition.


final_df = ts_tot_incv.join(ts_tot_incv_5,F.trim(ts_tot_incv["mkt_offr_src_cd"]) == F.trim(ts_tot_incv_5["source_code"]),"left_outer").select("mkt_offr_src_cd","offer_cd10","rp_offr_nm","bus_unit","compass_source_code","compass_offer_type").where((ts_tot_incv["mkt_offr_src_cd"] =="A") & (ts_tot_incv_5["bus_unit"] == "X")) # Applying left_outer join & selecting required columns & then applying where condition.

final_df.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("ts_tot") # This will create new table with ts_tot name & insert the data.
```

Comment: Kindly help on below functions how to convert in pyspark.  SELECT Trim(world_srvc_id) AS world_srvc_id,
regexp_replace(Trim(emp_lst_nm),'[^0-9a-zA-Z]',' ') AS emp_lst_nm,
        Trim(mgr_world_srvc_id) AS mgr_world_srvc_id,
        Trim(cas_id) AS cas_id,
        CASE
            WHEN ((Trim(desktop_id) = ''
            AND Trim(cas_id) > ' '))
                 THEN (Upper(Trim(cas_id)))
            ELSE (Trim(desktop_id))
        END AS desktop_id from table.

Comment: Yes above answer working but i need to fix the above problem mentioned.

Comment: I will check this one, can you please upvote or accept answer if it helps to solve actual question ?

Comment: I have accepted this as answer. Kindly please look into my above issue, I'm waiting for your response.

Comment: This code i have not tested, roughly converted query looks like - spark.table("table").select(F.trim("world_srvc_id").alias("world_srvc_id"),F.trim("emp_lst_nm"),F.trim("mgr_world_srvc_id").alias("mgr_world_srvc_id"),F.trim("cas_id").alias("cas_id"),F.trim("desktop_id"))
.withColumn("emp_lst_nm",F.regexp_replace(F.col("emp_lst_nm"),"[^0-9a-zA-Z]",' '))
.withColumn("desktop_id",when((F.col("desktop_id") == '' & F.col("cas_id"), F.upper("cas_id")).otherwise(F.col("desktop_id"))))

Comment: Facing below issue:    ivr_icm_cfs_lookup = spark.table("test_table").where(F.col("tier") == "Servicing").select("fig","fig_bu","tier") .withColumn("fig",F.regexp_replace(F.col("fig"),"[^0-9a-zA-Z]",' ')).withColumn("fig_bu",when((F.col("fig_bu") == 'OPEN' & F.col("tier") == 'Academy', F.upper("tier")).otherwise(F.col("fig_bu"))))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'when' is not defined

Comment: Kindly help on above issues.

Comment: F.when & try again

Comment: File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.3.2/python/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 116, in _
    njc = getattr(self._jc, name)(jc)
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.3.2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
"/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 332, in get_return_value  py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o90.and. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method and([class java.lang.String]) does not exist

Comment: I have tried F.when but got the above error. Please help me on this.

Comment: Sorry , I have check this issue i am not able figure it out. Can you please post this as new question, so that anyone can help you.

Comment: I am not able to post my question due to some technical issue. if will remove the case statement then code run fine , kindly suggest some other way to do case statement.